# How do I use user input to determine how the program works?

Tags: python

this is my first post here on stackoverflow and this is my first time using Python to make a program. I want to make a program to ask the user to input names of students then be able to add more information to that student as the program continues to run. Ideally I want the user to choose how many students there are, choose how many rounds are played, give them names, assign scores, and at the end output the final score and the averages of each student.

This is what I have currently:

```
name_students = list()
num_students = input("How many students?: ")
competitionRounds = input("How many rounds: ")
score_students = list ()
myList = name_students

for i in range(1, int(num_students) + 1):
name_students.append(input("Student Name: "))
print(name_students)


for i in range (1, int(competitionRounds)):
print(input(name_students [0] + " Total Score for each round: "))
```

This is how the program runs:

```
How many student?: 3 #Have the user input answers to these questions
How many rounds?: 2
Student Name: Nick
Student Name: Bob
Student Name: Lisa
Nick Total Score for each round:
```

I was trying to get it to ask for every name listed like

```
Nick Total Score for round 1:
Bob Total score for round 1:
Lisa Total score for round 1:
Nick Total score for round 2:
```

Etc.

I appreciate anyone who replies.

---Edit---
So I now have problems taking the numbers inputted by the user and adding them together by the name placed by the user.

My expected outcomes is:
    Nick Total Score for round 1: 2
    Bob Total score for round 1:3
    Lisa Total score for round 1:1
    Nick Total Score for round 2:2
    Bob Total score for round 2:3
    Lisa Total score for round 2:1
    Nick Total score for all rounds: 4
Etc

Currently my code looks like:

```
 name_students = list()
 num_students = input("How many students?: ")
 competitionRounds = input("How many rounds: ")
 score_students = []
 myList = name_students
 total_scores = 0, []


 for i in range(1, int(num_students) + 1):
   name_students.append(input("Student Name: "))

 for i in range (1, int(competitionRounds) +1):
    for j in range(len(name_students)):
     score_students.append(input(name_students [j] + " Total Score for round " + str(i) +": "))

 for i in range (1,int(competitionRounds) +1):
    for t in range(len(score_students)):
      print(name_students + score_students + total_scores)
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the last loop

```
for i in range (1, int(competitionRounds)):
    for j in range(len(name_students)):
         score_students.append(input(name_students [j] + " Total Score for round " + str(i) + ": "))
```

This will ask the user for each student's score for each round, and keep appending that to `score_students`. You may then manipulate that the way you want.

```
How many students?: 2
How many rounds: 3
Student Name: A
Student Name: B
['A', 'B']
A Total Score for round 1: 2
B Total Score for round 1: 1
A Total Score for round 2: 2
B Total Score for round 2: 1
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply I really appreciate it. I tried your code and it worked. I ran into a problem of adding the scores together, like adding A score for round 1 and 2 together.

Comment: That is a different question. Post the details of what you have tried and what errors you are getting. If your current question has been answered, you should accept the answer.